# What would be equivalent to this list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

The list comprehension:

```
def getBiggerNumber(input_number, generated_number):    
         return [x for x in generated_number if x > input_number]
```

The results from the list comprehension:

```
Generated Numbers : [7, 9, 14, 18, 27, 41, 44, 46, 54, 55, 57, 57, 57, 64, 65, 81, 82, 82, 83, 95]
Enter a number 1-100: 44
Your number: 44
Numbers greater than 44 : [46, 54, 55, 57, 57, 57, 64, 65, 81, 82, 82, 83, 95]
```

This code is what I tried to get the same result as the above.

```
for x in generated_number:
     if x > input_number:
          print(x)
```

The results I get from this is:

```
Random Numbers : [6, 12, 17, 24, 25, 26, 40, 43, 44, 45, 50, 51, 62, 65, 72, 75, 77, 91, 93, 98]
Please enter a number 1 through 100: 66
Your number is : 66
72
75
77
91
93
98
72
75
77
91
93
98
Numbers greater than 66 : None
```

Comment: You should append to a list in the second case, using `list.append` instead of printing.

Comment: And then return that list.

Comment: "i'm not geting the same results" is not something others can work with. - You should show the difference and what you expect.

Comment: The `for` loop should print the same things as are in the list that the list comprehension returns.

Comment: Your initial example is not very good. If `x` is the iterable, it should not also be the name of the iterator!

Comment: When I append it to a list, I only get one `x` that is greater than `input_number`. I want all of the generated numbers that are greater than the input number.

Comment: If you can show the result for each case then people can help you. Before that check indentation (May be your print stament is outside if condition)

Comment: I will add more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, step by step

```
def doThing(input_number,generated_number):
  return [x for x in generated_number if x > input_number]

print(doThing(10,[100,10,20,40]))

def doSameThing(input_number,generated_number):
  res = []
  for x in generated_number:
    if x > 10:
      res.append(x)

  return res

print(doSameThing(10,[100,10,20,40]))
```

You are making a filter by >10, list comprehension is just syntactic sugar of it

Comment: I believe I made a simple mistake by putting the `return res` under the if statement. Thanks!

Comment: @MCAbstract Do you mean that you actually wrote `return x` where the question says `print x`? Why didn't you put the actual code in the question?

Comment: `You are making a filter by >10, list comprehension is just syntactic sugar of it` this is not true. Even in Python 2 listcomps are not syntactic sugar for `map`/`filter`

Comment: @MCAbstract that's a common mistake don't worry! don't forget to vote if you like so.

Answer (score 1):

## Equivalent of list comprehensions

```
def getBiggerNumber(input_number, generated_number):
    return [x for x in generated_number if x > input_number]

print(getBiggerNumber(44, [20, 66, 100]))


def same(xnum, ylist, lst=[]):
    for x in ylist:
        if x > xnum:
            lst.append(x)
    return lst

print(same(44, [20, 66, 100]))
```

> OUTPUT:

```
[66, 100]
[66, 100]
>>>
```

Comment: graeat answer pal! check mine if you want :). Its a plus one